# Как реализовать правило htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

В wordpress нужно, чтобы при открытии ссылки по типу:

> site.ru/from-(*)

Открывалась информация с адреса:

> site.ru/index.php?cat=2&from=$1

Пробовал так:

```
RewriteRule ^from-(.*) index.php?cat=2&from=$1
```

Не работает...

Comment: @DigitalCore ответы - в ответы )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^data.php$ data/index.php [L]
```

Учитывая комментарий ниже, внесу изменения относительно кода, и потребностей ТС.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^from-(.*)$ index.php?cat=2&from=$1 [L]
```

При таком вызове [http://example.com/from-привет-мир](http://example.com/from-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80) откроется файл по пути http://example.com/index.php?cat=2&from=$1 но в командной строке будет отображено [http://example.com/from-привет-мир](http://example.com/from-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80).

**index.php**

```
echo "каталог = ".$_GET["cat"]." ::  запрос = ".$_GET["from"];
```

**Результат:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И чем мне это должно помочь ?

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene вместо минусов подставил-бы свои значения, это прямой ответ на твой вопрос!

Comment: Каких минусов? )

Comment: Короче я не знаю читали ли ты вопрос ну или я очень туп, но мне кажется, что в моём примере небыло ни data.php ни data...

Comment: Спасибо большое) Я понял в чем косяк)))

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene использовал data.php, и вложенный каталог для наглядного примера, а ещё для того чтоб вы дошли сами до решения вопроса - так вы запомнили бы. а копи паст плохая практика. скопировал и забыл. как-то так. Всегда пожалуйста пользуйтесь.

Comment: Ну кстати вроде всё верно сделано, но не работает... 404 всё равно.

Comment: Причём я делал уже ранее так: 
RewriteRule ^get/([^\/]+) index.php?m=get&geo=$1
И это работает...

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene я добавил тестовые файлы, и результаты, обратите внимание.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80996/discussion-between-shevtsov-eugene-and-digital-core).

Comment: Я понимаю, что это должно работать, но вот у меня не пашет. Более того. Я прописываю это-же правило, но с редиректом и редирект работает...